# Chtml::purifier not working

Tags: php, yii, htmlpurifier

i am trying to use Chtml::prifier to linkify content but the links are not been linkified. Is there any other configuration setting i need to take care of.

```
    public function actionTime() {
    $p = new CHtmlPurifier();
    $p->options = array('URI.AllowedSchemes'=>array(
        'http' => true,
        'https' => true,
    ));

    echo $p->purify("http://testsite.com");

    $this->beginWidget('CHtmlPurifier');
    echo "all http://anothersite.com";
    $this->endWidget();
    }
```

In both cases, i am getting the text as it is as output.
yii version 1.1.14

Answer (score 1):

Try  to do like this example :

```
echo "Try to input some html tags and see what tag does it filter : ";
echo CHtml::beginForm();
echo CHtml::textArea('user_input');
echo "<br/>";
echo CHtml::submitButton();
echo CHtml::endForm();

echo "<br/><br/>The result: <br/>";
echo $user_input;

echo "<br/><br/>The result in html: <br/>";
echo CHtml::encode($user_input);
```

XssController.php :

```
public function actionHtmlPurifier(){
               $user_input = null;
               if (isset($_POST['user_input'])){
                       $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
               }

               $parser=new CHtmlPurifier(); //create instance of CHtmlPurifier
               $user_input=$parser->purify($user_input); //we purify the $user_input

               $this->render("htmlpurifier", array('user_input'=>$user_input));
       }
```

I recommended you to use this extension, I tested it before .

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/input

Comment: I am sorry. I misunderstood the functioning of html purifier. What i wanted is something which can convert http://example.com to a tag and thought purifier will do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. I misunderstood the functioning of html purifier. What i wanted is something which can convert example.com to "a" tag and thought purifier will do so. I will use the regex instead to convert it to "a" tag and then display it with purifier.